# LPAD in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to figure out LPAD function in SQL Server. I found some syntax but the result is not what I'm expecting. The column ID is defined as `varchar`. I want to replicate dependent string '04130' based on the length of ID column. Any hints is highly appreciated. Thanks

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    RIGHT(REPLICATE('04130', 12)+LEFT(ID, 12), 12) --- (LPAD in sql server)
FROM 
    S_Information_Tab;
```

This is the output I'm getting

```
ID     (No column name)
6452    130041306452
6495    130041306495
```

This is the **expected** output:

```
ID    (No column name)             
6452  041300416452
6495  041300416495
```

Comment: OK, so first you replicate the `04130` string 12 times, giving `041300413004130041300413004130041300413004130041300413004130`, then you add the first twelve characters of the `ID`, which is `6452`, so less than 12, so you add them all, giving you `0413004130041300413004130041300413004130041300413004130041306452`, then you take the rightmost 12 characters of that, giving you `130041306452`, can you explain *what you want* other than *results is not what I'm expecting*?

Comment: Rather, can you explain what you want, why you want it, what rules does that output follow? Because this part is not at all clear in your question.

Comment: Lasse V. Karlsen makes a good point.  If you need some help and advice, on formatting your question, take a peek [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are all your IDs four digits?  Some of the answers depend on that.  Are ID lengths variable

Comment: Yes, ID length is variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand your issue.  The length of the replicated string is dependent on the length of your `ID`.  I think it would be best to find the length of the string, subtract that from the final length then concat your replicated string as below:

```
select concat(substring(REPLICATE('04130', 12),1,12-len(id)),id)
  FROM S_Information_Tab;
```

Comment: may as well skip replicate and use '041300413004130'

Comment: @AlexK. was thinking about that, I added back in Replicate * 12, was wondering why it was 12 and i guess if this string was to be semi-dynamic, they could change it to one char string and when combined with null if would fill 12 spaces ie (`replicate('a',12)+null)

Comment: its 12 i think because the question code is a copied version of padding with lead zero or another single char. 3 is fine I think as 5 (length of string) * 3 is the first value > 12.

Comment: Thanks it answers my problem. You were right replicated string is dependent on the length of the column ID and I have to left PAD.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your ID is of nvarchar type, this would give you the expected OUTPUT.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    CONCAT(LEFT(REPLICATE('04130', 12),8),LEFT(ID,4))
FROM
    S_information_tab;
```

Also check these links:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx

---

For testing purpose

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP (
    ID NVARCHAR(10) 
);

INSERT INTO #TMP (ID)
VALUES
('6452')
,('6495');

SELECT
    ID
    ,CONCAT(LEFT(REPLICATE('04130', 12),8),LEFT(ID,4))
FROM
    #TMP;

DROP TABLE #TMP;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve the desired result is:

```
-- Prefixing a string field.
SELECT      
    '04130041' + ID
FROM 
    (
        -- Embedded sample rows.
        VALUES
            ('6452'),
            ('6495')
    ) AS S_Information_Tab(ID)
;
```

Here I've used a [table value constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to generate the sample values from your question.

[Left](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) returns *x* characters from the start of a string.  If the required number exceeds the length of the string, the entire string is returned.  Examples:

```
-- Left examples.
SELECT
    LEFT('123', 1) AS [R1], 
    LEFT('123', 2) AS [R2], 
    LEFT('123', 3) AS [R3],
    LEFT('123', 4) AS [R4]
;
```

Returns

```
R1  R2  R3  R4
1   12  123 123
```